# Error: "Cannot find name 'module'" in vim and tsuquyomi typescript plugin

Tags: vim, typescript, vim-plugin

I am getting this error every time the transpiler run on save. 
Vim + Tsuguyomi typescript plugin.

```
src/app/app.component.ts|5 col 13 error| TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.                  
node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts|| TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/async.d.ts|| TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/async.d.ts|| TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/lang.d.ts|| TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/lang.d.ts|| TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/lang.d.ts|| TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts|| TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts|| TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts|| TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
```

Comment: Are you able to find that manually? Are you sure that it exists?

Comment: @SibiCoder Yes. And other editor like Atom with other typescript plugin find its. I think the declarations come from es6-shim, which typings.d.ts does refers to, so I don't know why the vim plugin can't find it.